# Menu element does not work after using jquery replace with

Tags: jquery, replacewith

Hi to everyone I'm kind of confused here. I'm replacing an element using `replaceWith();` from jQuery and it works good. But after transformation the clickable element does not work anymore. Here is my [code](http://jsfiddle.net/napstercake/RTPhR/)

Comment: I'm not sure how you sidestepped the no jsFiddle links without code in your question, but please post the code here.

Comment: @j08691 `replaceWith();` is formatted as code. I opened [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193086/require-multi-line-code-blocks-when-using-jsfiddle-links) on meta.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry For that @j08691. I thought it was better that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because the event binding is lost when you replace the element. `replaceWith()` essentially removes the element and all its event bindings and then replaces it with a new element. It does not persist the event bindings.

Bind the click event using `.on()` instead.

```
$('.menu').on('click', 'a', function() {
   ...
});
```

**Updated Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/RTPhR/1/

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/RTPhR/5/
Bind the event to the menu not to the LINKS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.menu').on('click','a',function() {
        var $this = $(this),
            element = $this.attr('name');

        if (element == 'opt1') {
            alert('opcion 1');

        } else if (element == 'opt2') {
            alert('opcion 2');
            $this.replaceWith("<a href='#' name='cerrar'>VOLVER</a>");

        } else if (element == 'cerrar') {
            alert('close!');
        }
    });
});
```